# OPening multiple copies of ACCESS app

Tags: ms-access

Environment: Windows 7, ACCESS 10, SQL Server.
Have an ACCESS app that resides in a single location on a server.  I want to allow three users to use this app at the same time. The app is read only to SQL Server, but currently only one user can use the app at a time.  If one is open the others will not open till the open one is closed.  Looked all over the web, and went through options in ACCESS.  How do I set it up so all can use it at the same time.

Thanks

jpl

Comment: What error does the second user get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy and recommended workaround is to distribute a copy of the Access file to each workstation so each user has an independent copy.

Comment: I thought of that but we have other apps that are open more than once at a time. Just makes things easier if there is only one copy of the app.

Comment: Don't know what I did but but we can now open the app more than once. Just made a vba change to the program and now it's ok.

Comment: Great. But when you get into trouble next time, return to this question.